# Compare Object Property Keys with Object Property Values in Array, Return "Total Points"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, for-in-loop

Link to [Codewars kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/total-amount-of-points/train/javascript). Basically, as far as I understand:

- If the property key (`x`) is greater than the property value (`y`), add 3 points to `points`.
- If the property key(`x`) is less than the property value (`y`), add 0 points to `points`.
- If the property key (`x`) is equal to the property value (`y`), add 1 point to `points`.

I need to iterate through each individual property to compare the `x` value against the `y` value. But what I'm trying isn't working:

```
function points(games) {

  let points = 0;

  for (let key in games) {
    let item = games[key];
    let x = item[0];
    let y = item[1];
    //compare x values against y values in items
    if (x > y) {
      points += 3;
    }
    if (x < y) {
      points += 0;
    }
    if (x === y) {
      points += 1;
    }
  }
  return points;
}

console.log(points(["1:0", "2:0", "3:0", "4:0", "2:1", "3:1", "4:1", "3:2", "4:2", "4:3"]));
```

This is returning 0.

How can I iterate through each property in the array to do the comparison in *each individual property*?

**EDIT** - After splitting strings into arrays for comparison, I am still not grasping how to compare `x` values in the arrays agains the `y` values:

```
function points(games) {
  let points = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
    let properties = games[i].split();

    if (properties[0] > properties[1]) {
      points += 3;
    }
    if (properties[0] < properties[1]) {
      points += 0;
    }
    if (properties[0] === properties[1]) {
      points += 1;
    }
  }
  return points;
}
```

Comment: You're passing in an array of colon-separated strings, not objects or arrays. You'd need to either split the string, or pass in different data.

Comment: Oh, would it have been an object if they were surrounded by `{}` instead of `[]`?

Comment: It wouldn't run because that would be invalid syntax.

Comment: Since the challenge is supposed to take an array of strings you'll want to find out how to split strings in JS.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Thx for the clarification, I'll rework my code.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm still not understanding how to compare the first value in the array against the second, for each array in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for further information

```js
function points(games) {

  return games.map(game => {
    let points = 0;
    let item = game.split(':');
    let x = item[0];
    let y = item[1];
    //compare x values against y values in items
    if (x > y) {
      points += 3;
    }
    if (x < y) {
      points += 0;
    }
    if (x === y) {
      points += 1;
    }
    return points;
  }).reduce((sum, curr) => (sum += curr),0);
}

console.log(points(["1:0", "2:0", "3:0", "4:0", "2:1", "3:1", "4:1", "3:2", "4:2", "4:3"]));
```

Comment: Ah - so you can do the entire comparison within a `.map()` method - thank you.

Comment: They way you had it before was easier to understand - now you have a return within a return?

Comment: do you want to sum  the final result of all the points, like [3,3,3] and the final result would be 9 ?

Comment: Yes we can certainly do that - it was easier to understand when we were adding points within the map, and returning the sum of the points after, though. Either way your code works : )